# Endianness and Socket Programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, endianness

I'm making a program that communicate with certain patient monitor using C sockets. I'm using connection-less sockets (UDP) to communicate with the device. But there is endianness mis-match between my computer and device and so far I was doing this to get parse response from the patient monitor:

```
recvfrom(int socket, char *buffer, size_t length, int flags,
             struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t *address_len);
```

Then I was casting the buffer directly to structure and using the ntohs and ntohl to change the byte ordering, for example:

```
struct A * a = (struct A *)buffer;
Struct A b;
b.v1 = ntohs(a->v1);
b.v2 = ntohl(a->v2);
```

After reading few examples over internet, I figured out that this may be wrong approach due to compiler dependent padding. But I'm not sure about it. I need simple way to un-marshall a buffer to a C structure with correct endiannes. The structure that I'm receiving can be of unpredictable length and little complex as well. I need fast and easy approach to do the un-marshalling.

I don't control sender. Sender is in network byte order. My question is only that:-
Is is safe to cast a buffer to a structure and then use ntohs and ntohl on this casted structure to make host-byte order replica of this structure? Is it a fastest approach? If not, then what can be the fastest approach?

Comment: do you control the sender as well?  Do they send packets in network byte-order?

Comment: i think your solution is right already, you can use `__attribute__((packed))` or `aligned(x)` to make sure the compiler doesn't pad your structure.

Comment: convert to network byte order when putting data on the wire and convert to host order when taking off the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since `a` is apointer, your code should at minimum do this...

```
b.v1 = ntohs(a->v1);
b.v2 = ntohl(a->v2);
```

Second of all, the answer depends on circumstances and specification of the patient monitor.   Who writes the code for the patient monitor?  Is there a specification for it? What machine architecture is it using(in case you know),  are you dealing with just one model or  are there many versions of the monitor -- can you change the monitor, etc. etc.

Im going to assume that you *cannot* change the monitor, and that the byte order is documented somewhere -- and you *may* have to create your own unpack/pack routines, by doing byte addressing and bit manipulation -- that is unless you know that the format exactly matches that of "network" order -- and that padding of structs are the same in the network buffer.

So something like;

```
void unpack(struct *b, unsigned char *buffer)
{
   b->v1 = (buffer[0] <<8)|(buffer[1]);   
   b->v2 = (buffer[2] <<24)|(buffer[3] <<16)|(buffer[4] <<8)|(buffer[5]);
   etc....
}
```

or like this if you prefer to you ntohX;

```
void unpack(struct *b, unsigned char *buffer)
{
   b->v1 = ntohs(buffer+0);   
   b->v2 = ntohl(buffer+2);
   etc....
}
```

However if you *do* control the monitor code, then using a tool like [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) would get rid of all the complexity of doing bit manipulation and worry about byte orders....

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply. I wrote the code on instance made little mistake. :) Could explain what kind of specifications you are talking about?

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. But still, instead of hard coding all the bit manipulations, can I just cast the buffer to my structure and use ntohs on individual  attributes of structure? Also, is the above approach independent of endianness of host computer?

Comment: You could do that using a buffer offset, so like  
`b.v1 = ntohs(buffer+offset1);  
b.v2 = ntohl(buffer+offset2);`  so that you take out the variability of the padding for the monitor

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any speed difference in two approaches?

Comment: Speedwise -- if you by any change have a big indian machine, then htohl may be faster as it would be a empty-macro -- however on a little Indian machine (i.e. all intel based machines) they would do the same speed, and choice is just a coding style  (I find the bit manipulation easier to read myself, but opinions differ)