# Network byte order on localhost

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock, endianness

I'm developing a network application using [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. Whenever I test the application to send a few bytes for example in an array:

```
char[0] = '1';
char[1] = '2';
char[2] = '3';
char[3] = '4';
char[4] = '\0';
```

I use the [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) socket to receive the bytes on another application running on localhost then the byte order doesn't seem to be changed at all. Is it just because I'm testing it on localhost server? Will the network byte order change as:

```
char[0] = '\0';
char[1] = '4';
char[2] = '3';
char[3] = '2';
char[4] = '1';
```

if I receive it over the Internet?

Comment: As much as I understand it (and this has been a source of confusion for me), I believe endianness is only a factor when you're serializing a multibyte object. It's the bytes *within* an object that get reordered. Here you're sending `char`s which are single byte, so cannot be rearranged. It's not that your whole stream gets reordered. I'm not certain of this, so confirmation would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Endianness and Socket Programming in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858610/endianness-and-socket-programming-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8-bit character arrays and strings do not get hit with network byte order issues. Since each individual char in the array is already in order with itself and sequenced with the next char byte in the array... It's the short, ints, and longs that get impacted.

Also, it's not the send and recv calls that do any byte swapping. Byte swapping is related to how the processor lays out integers in memory:

To understand byte order issues, consider the following code on an Intel chip:

```
// code that demonstrates how integer values are laid out in memory
int msg = 0x01020304;
char* buffer = (char*)&msg;
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
```

The result that gets printed out is:

```
4 3 2 1
```

What this shows is that x86 processors order the bytes of memory of integers in the opposite order you might expect. The least significant byte or an integer is sequenced first in memory. This is Little Endian.

On a Sparc chip such as old a Sun workstation, that same code prints out:

```
1 2 3 4
```

This is Big Endian.

It's only when you write out data to disk or network that the Endianness of the memory sequence matters. As soon as another computer reads the byte sequence written out by another computer, then the CPU reading the integer will interpret it based on it's own endianness.

Endianness typically matters on when writing integers to file or streaming to network. Without a conversion by the application developer, the raw buffer passed to send() gets transmitted exactly as the processor lays the bytes out in memory.  See [htonl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) and friends for more details on converting integers and shorts to and from Big Endian (aka Network byte order).

Comment: But if I'm going to send an integer say int `i = 256;` I'll need to convert it into an array of characters and pass the buffer to socket. So, where does the endianness comes into this?

Comment: Convert i to network byte order prior to sending.  Example: `int j = htonl(i); send(sock, (char*)&j, sizeof(j), 0);`  Likewise, do a ntohl() call on the received integer when receiving it back.

Comment: Ah I see. I was doing it the other way. Using bitshifts to convert `int i` into an array of chars `char buffer[4]` and then `send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` So when I interpreted the buffer as `int` back on the other end I didn't notice any difference since everything was already in bytes and the way I sent it.

Comment: Why would I need to use `htonl` function to convert it manually to big endian byte order? I thought it does this automatically.

Comment: Nothing is done automatically. however, if all the nodes on your network are x86  (little endian), then you don't have to do any of this byte order conversion stuff. It's your protocol. And if you decide that your protocol sends data in little endian, then you can do that. But should your protocol ever need to interoperate with a big endian computer, then you have a byte order problem to deal with. Most all internet protocols are written to assume big endian as network byte order.

Answer (score 2):

Endianness only comes into play when you look at a byte stream and decide to interpret the data.

For example if you've got the byte stream:

```
'1' '2' '3' '4' '0'
```

And you decided to interpret the data as a stream of characters then, assuming one byte per character, you've got an array containing the string "1234".

However, if you decide to interpret the data as an `int` then endianness comes into play as you've got more than one byte used to encode the data type (int). The values of the above stream have the hex values:

```
0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x00
```

(0x31 is the hex value of '1' etc)

This is where the endianness comes into play. You need to know the endianness of the data in the stream so that you can successfully convert it back to the right value when you deserialize it.

Comment: But if I'm going to send an integer say `int i = 256;` I'll need to convert it into an array of characters and pass the buffer to socket. So, where does the Endianness comes into this?

Comment: @cpx - if you want to send an `int` type then you can convert it to network byte order using `htonl` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then, when you read it back use `ntohl` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @cpx - if you know you're only ever going to send the data to x86 or x64 hardware then you could choose to ignore byte ordering issues, as both sender and receiver have the same endianness

Comment: Ah I see. I was doing it the other way. Using bitshifts to convert `int i` into an array of chars `char buffer[4]` and then `send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` So when I interpreted the buffer as `int` back on the other end I didn't notice any difference since everything was already in bytes and the way I sent it.